# Toast message is appearing even though password and confirm password match

Tags: java, android, authentication

```
package com.example.chris.thegiver;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // calls the constructor of the DatabaseHelper class which will create the database and table
    DatabaseHelper registerDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
    }

    public void onRegisterClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.btnReg) {

            EditText etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
            EditText etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
            EditText etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
            EditText etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
            EditText etConfirm = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etConfirm);


            String name = etName.getText().toString();
            String email = etEmail.getText().toString();
            String user = etUsername.getText().toString();
            String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
            String confirm = etConfirm.getText().toString();

            if (password.equals(confirm)) {
                Contact c = new Contact(); 
                c.setName(name);
                c.setEmail(email);
                c.setUsername(user);
                c.setPassword(password);

                registerDB.insertContact(c);
            }
            else {
                // Pop up message It skips the original if statement for some reason
                Toast pass = Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Passwords Dont Match!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                pass.show();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I test the app, the password, and confirm password are equal but for some reason when it reaches the if statement it skips over the original if and goes straight to the else

Comment: please post only relevant code and explain your issue.

Comment: Print the values of "password" and "confirm" before - if (password.equals(confirm)) {

Comment: What isnt relevant about this code? I am only having trouble with this one block. I am not trying to argue and thank you for the criticism I am trying to learn how to properly post code on here due to I am very new at stack overflow

Comment: I tried using System.out.println(confirm) and System.out.println(password) and nothing happened

Comment: Typo. Check the ID that you are using for `etPassword` and make sure it is what you want. With regards to relevant code. The XML layout is very relevant.

Answer (score 1):

The only possible reason for this, according to the provided code are one of these two:

```
EditText etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
EditText etConfirm = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etConfirm);
```

These ids are not what they say they are. Check on the xml layout and make sure both these edittext id are in fact the ones you think they are. For example, you may have swaped `username` and `password` id due to copy-paste and haven't noticed.

Or: You are adding empty spaces and altough you do not see it, the text is indeed different

EDIT: Just checked with more attention. The problem is here:

```
EditText etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
EditText etConfirm = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etConfirm);
```

Reason one is confirmed

Comment: user3806331 Thank you so much. I was looking at this for hours and must have skipped past that typo. Thank you again

Comment: When something so obvious doesn't happen, an obvious user fault happened xD